# Interpreting the notation $l(y,\hat{y}) = \mathbb I\lbrace\hat{y}\neq y \rbrace$

Tags: matrices, notation

I was reading ["Some Elements of Learning Theory" (Google Drive link)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/111Ksg89iDZPY2SNQZ_FF3iAc_cC-6SLm/view) and I am curious about this notation (On slide 20: Ingredients, Zero-one loss):

$$l(y,\hat{y}) = \mathbb I\lbrace\hat{y}\neq y \rbrace$$

Which, for me, means that $l$ is equal to $1$  whenever $\hat{y} \neq y$ and $0$ otherwise. Also, $\mathbb I$ is the identity matrix.

So, my questions:

1. What is your interpretation for the aformentioned equation?
2. Is this a regular way to express and identityt matrix? If not...
3. What would be the correct way to express and identity matrix that have ones depending on a condition?

Comment: $\mathbb I$ is sometimes used to mean 'indicator function.'  And that agrees with your interpretation.  Another notation is the Kronecker delta: $\delta_{y,\hat y}$.

Comment: $\mathbb I$ here stands for the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), not the identity matrix.

Comment: Yeap, you both are right. Thanks for your help.